# Register laptop name on office router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

I make webpages, and every time i have a meeting with my customers they want to connect to my laptop and see the webpage running on their devices (Pcs, Phones, tablets etc), for that i need to find my ip address and give it to them so they can type it in their browsers

Is not a big problem, but Im just wondering if its possible to somehow register my laptop's host-name on my customers network so they only need to enter a name (name, FQDN or hostname anything will do) in their browsers instead of an ip address, because as you know, is easier to remember a name instead of a number

I do know that many home and small office routers have built in DNS and DHCP servers, and many are factory preconfigured, but i dont know there is a way to use this system to make my web server available through the local network

Im running both Apache2 in Linux Mint and IIS on Windows 7 Professional, is it possible? do i need to install anything else on each of my OSes to accomplish this?

Regards...

Comment: You cannot control the network situation at a random client. @Jakuns answer will work in most cases. Hopefully that is enough. If not you might want to set up your website on a reachable webserver somewhere on the Internet (which will have a fixed name/IP/setup and is not subject to whatever your laptop gets at a client).

Comment: The best solution you should buy  (shared hosting/VPS/dedicated) or host your own webserver. Hosting your own and using, say, a dynamic DNS service is easy and cheap for a developer.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop gets ip from dhcp on local office router then your laptop's name is automatically registerd on that dhcp server. In most cases your's laptop name should be seen on local network under the address http://YourLaptopName.local
Please check it first at your home router management page where you can find exact name of your laptop seen from router perspective.
Best Regards

Comment: This might work most of the time, but ` your home router management page ` is a problem since it is not the posters home router but whatever is availble at the clients. And not all of those might be configured to support that. (e.g. guest might be on their own VLAN and subnet).

Comment: To check `your home router management page ` it is one time job to confirm that he knows what is his laptop name exactly, seen from the network.  It's **not** to check it every time at different locations. And this can be easily done at his home router, that's why I suggest it. Just for confirmation.

Comment: If your laptop connect to my network I will assign it the name "guest01". I will ignore whatever name the laptop has set on its own and you will be able to reach it using http://guest1...